# Pass image of any size to Pytorch ViT pretrained model

Tags: deep-learning, pytorch, transformer-model

```
import torch
from torchvision import models

model = models.vit_b_32(pretrained=True ,image_size=320)
model.eval()
```

The above piece of code is failing at Line 3 with the below error:

```
ValueError: The parameter 'image_size' expected value 224 but got 320 instead.
```

So does Pytorch's pre-trained Vision Transformer model take only a fixed shape input image size unlike pre-trained ResNet's which are flexible with the image size ?

I am shying a bit from downsizing my image as I am trying to perform Crack-detection on some samples. After downsizing to 224, the crack pixels become far too small which I believe my affect my model's performance.
When I train my model on ResNets, I get the optimal performance for image shapes > 400px

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found that I will have to stick to this dimensions if I want to use this pretrained model.
An another alternative is to use `ViT_B_16_Weights.IMAGENET1K_SWAG_E2E_V` weights which has an image dimension of (384,384)

Comment: There should be some other ways.